# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (10) - Unable to connect to Upstart

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows-10-preview

Running the Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS release (Trusty) using the new windows beta release with "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" support.  I'm having issues running services requiring upstart. ie:

`[15:08 root@localhost ~] > start ttyS0
[15:08 root@localhost ~] > start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: No such file or directory.`

It looks like the upstart daemon isn't running at all.  I've checked the log file location for upstart /var/log/upstart/ there are no files there though there are many upstart config files in /etc/init/.  I've been unable to find any information about how to manually start/restart the upstart daemon itself.

Thanks for any assistance in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has been [discussed before](https://superuser.com/questions/1064801/i-broke-the-windows-linux-subsystem-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10-linux-help). It's [a known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/143) and the quick-fix [suggested by Canonical](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/143#issuecomment-209072634) is to run :

```
cat > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
exit 101
EOF
chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

A real [fix is available](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/143#issuecomment-210667524) but not yet released to the Fast Ring:

> A fix for the udev apt update issues is on it's way to the flighting branch. When the fix reaches the branch new subsystem installs will no longer have this issue.

Comment: This only will remove error messages associated with using upstart/initctl.  Given that there is a real fix available in the future from microsoft and no fix will be available prior to that I'm going to say this is the best answer to my question.  Thanks for the footwork.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what it says. Upstart does not exist. Windows 10 has bash and certain other parts of Ubuntu. They never said anything about Upstart.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/554377/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-upstart-i-have  This thread suggests that this version of ubuntu is not shipped with upstart.  I wonder why initctl is attempting to use upstart since this is the case.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's reasonable, but it definitely restricts a lot of the functionality that you'd get. Can you advise a workaround, perhaps installing it manually?

Comment: I've never used it. A Win10 update made my Win half unbootable and I've just been using Ubuntu 15.10 with KDE.