# I broke the Windows Linux Subsystem (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10). Linux Help?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10

I have been playing with the new linux subsystem on Windows and somehow i have broken it and now most of Ubuntu's internals (apt-get,dpkg, etc) don't work. Everything i try something i get the same message...

```
    Setting up udev (204-5ubuntu20.19) ...
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: No such file or directory
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
 * udev requires devtmpfs support, not started
   ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd-services:
 systemd-services depends on udev (>= 175-0ubuntu23); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd-services (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on systemd-services (= 204-5ubuntu20.19); however:
  Package systemd-services is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 systemd-services
 libpam-systemd:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is there a "reset" or uninstall/reinstall option? That's probably the easiest & fastest. Any idea what you did to have this happen? Erase root (`/`) or something?

Comment: Per [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614970/vivid-failed-to-connect-to-upstart-connection-refused), try:

`sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv`

for a quick fix - that post has a link to the "recommended" fix as well. Not sure it's the same problem, but it looks like it _might_ be related.

Comment: I was trying to get xserver to work after reading that someone got it working on windows... i think i might have installed to new of a version. But not entirely sure what caused it. Apt-get wont install anything with out giving me that error. I tried removing the feature from windows and re adding it but it just loads the same subsystem configuration as before; can't find a way to reload default anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/reset to factory Ubuntu in Windows 10 Insider Preview 14316](http://superuser.com/questions/1065569/how-to-remove-reset-to-factory-ubuntu-in-windows-10-insider-preview-14316)

Comment: @ Ramhound I did not ask how to reinstall Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10, i asked how to fix the problem. I have never had this problem in actually Ubuntu. If going Nuclear is fixing problems, then i don't want to be around when they fix global warming

Comment: @MikePengelly - What order a question is asked, doesn't decide if it can or cannot be a duplicate of another question, its the order they were answered in even then its just a matter of saying the answer of an existing answer also answers this question.

Comment: @Ramhound But i doesn't answer my question. That's like saying "reinstall windows every time you get an error message" or "buy a new car every time you hear a noise".... It solves to problem but its not a practical solution.

Comment: You can blame Jonas for submitting an identical answer as another question, only reason I flagged it, to be honest.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fixed it.

Ran:

```
apt-get remove upstart
```

then

```
apt-get remove udev
```

then

```
apt-get autoremove
```

and it all seems to be working now.

Comment: Must have installed when i installed x11 (a too new version) ... btw x server has to run in windows not in the linux subsystem. and then you forward the application by running DISPLAY=0: firefox

Answer (score 34):

**Warning, this process will restore Lxss to initial config**

To reinstall the Lxss open Windows `cmd` as administrator and run:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>LxRun.exe /uninstall
```

Then:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>LxRun.exe /install
```

Comment: I did not mark this as the answer because it is a nuclear approach to the problem i was having. Yes it would fix it (in theory, i did not try), but the way i fixed it correct my exact problem with out going nuclear. But if i continue to have problem i would recommend this approach if you want to save hours. In the future though i doubt people would want to reconfigure there Linux Subsystem every time something goes wrong.

Comment: The problem is with the Ubuntu subsystem itself. Reinstalling it won't fix anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for those of us finding the question via google (having made a mess in our installs): I can assure you the answer is still very much appreciated!

Comment: You guys are right, this isn't the answer and we should use this as last option.

Comment: I'm getting a `Access is denied.` when I run `C:\WINDOWS\system32>LxRun.exe /uninstall` even if the cmd session is being run "as Administrator". Any ideas?

Comment: runing `lxrun /uninstall /full` will remove the Ubuntu environment as well as any modifications, new applications, and user data. After successful uninstalling run `lxrun /install` command to install subsystem.

http://superuser.com/a/1065579/373485

Answer (score 9):

The official response from microsoft

**[github:Microsoft/BashOnWindows](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/143#issuecomment-209072634)**

> This is an issue that everyone will start seeing. We need to add
>   something on this in our official docs.
>
> As @nuclearmistake points out, udev is something that breaks in
>   apt-get but the errors should not cause any issues in WSL. We have
>   reached out to Canonical on this one asking for the best solution and
>   they recommend the following changes:
>
> Write the following to /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
>
> `#!/bin/sh 
>   exit 101`
>
> chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
>
> dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
>
> ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
>
> I have tried this one myself and it looks to work quite well.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a more targeted solution.  Create a script named `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d` (`nano /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`) with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    udev|systemd-logind) exit 101;;
esac
```

Save and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).  Mark the script as executable (`chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`).  This script tells `dpkg` not to attempt to start `udev` or `systemd-logind`.

You will then be able to complete the previously failing `dpkg` configuration step (`dpkg --configure -a`).

Comment: This is an answer that could be improved by _explaining what happened_, what the "somehow" in the question actually was and how this series of steps addresses it.  [Here is one pointer](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11488599) to use.  [Here is another](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/143).