# How to remove/reset Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows Insider Build 14316

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows-10-preview, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed the `Windows Subsystem for Linux` on Windows 10 Insider Preview build 14316. Now I would like to remove it or, better, revert to its factory defaults i.e. as it was when just installed.

I tried, to remove it from the "Turn Windows features on or off" windows, with no luck. I tried, to mark it as "off" in the above windows and delete its files manually located in `%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/lxss`, with no luck.

Has anyone succeeded in removing/resetting the Ubuntu user-mode environment?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

**The following answer only applies to WSL on Windows 10 1703 and 1607.** WSL on Windows 10 1709+ can be installed from within the Windows Store UWP application.

If you want to remove and reset the Linux subsystem, open a command prompt with elevated permissions and enter the following commands:

```
lxrun /uninstall /full 

lxrun /install
```

On modern versions of Windows the command to uninstall the default WSL distribution is as follows:

```
wsl --unregister
```

Sources:

1. https://www.slightfuture.com/technote/lxss-lxrun
2. [Installing Fish Shell on Ubuntu on Windows 10](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingFishShellOnUbuntuOnWindows10.aspx)
3. [HOWTO: Ubuntu on Windows | Ubuntu Insights](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/14/howto-ubuntu-on-windows-2/)

Comment: @BenCreasy - What’s your point? It was correct when it was submitted. In fact it’s still correct.

Comment: It's one of the highest voted WSL posts on SU but doesn't help 99.999% of people looking for help at this point. Just unforunate.

Comment: @BenCreasy - Majority of those votes were in 2016. There are lots of contributions that are about Windows XP which are completely irrelevant. I disagree this is one of the highest voted WSL answers on SU. I better received answer to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems with installing BASH, it would always hang at "Expanding Filesystem...". When I ran

```
lxrun /uninstall /full
```

it would error out.

To fix this, I did a reboot. Ran this again as soon as the computer came back up. This worked. Then I found there is [an issue related to installing the BASH prompt](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/565).

And someone brought up about pagefiles. I have four drives and three of them had pagefiles. I set the pagefile to one drive and set it to be automatically managed. Rebooted the computer. Then I was able to install the BASH prompt for Windows, but instead of using `lxrun /install` I used

```
bash.exe -c "ps auxf"
```