# Bash storage on Windows 10

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Where on the file system does Bash for Windows get installed?

If I find that it becomes bloated (because over time I installed a lot of apt packages or something) what is the best way to purge it and start over?

I know that it downloads and initializes on the first run, so I was wondering if I could simply delete the folder where it is stored and start over again, make back ups, manage multiple versions of my workspace, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: lxss stores data within the %USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/lxss directory.  But backing up that directory alone isn't enough.  [How you reset lxss is well documented](http://superuser.com/questions/1065569/how-to-remove-reset-windows-subsystem-for-linux-on-windows-insider-build-14316/1065579#1065579)

Comment: Thanks! This might help too (official MS docs) https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/

Comment: This question overlaps http://superuser.com/questions/1067373/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resetting the Bash Subsystem is pretty easy. To uninstall it fully, use the following command:

```
lxrun /uninstall /full
```

To reinstall it, use this command:

```
lxrun /install
```

This will re-download it from the Windows Store - it is not that large and you will get a completely fresh copy. If you really screw up, re-downloading might be the only way to go.

Comment: How much space does the Bash Subsystem use in total for a fresh install?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, you must use `wslconfig` (instead of `lxrun`) to manage the WSL distributions. You can [read the documentation from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/wsl/wsl-config#managing-multiple-linux-distributions).

Note that you can install multiple linux distributions in your WSL. To list the distributions you have, you can use:

```
wslconfig /list /all
```

To remove a distribution, you must unregister it. The WSL will keep the installer but it will remove all the programs and user data.

```
wslconfig /unregister <DistributionName>
```