# When entering command on Windows 10 Bash on Ubuntu, nothing is returned

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, powershell

When I first ran the bash file, it asked me to put a user name, I put "admin" and it said there was already a username and it told me to add a user later. So I screwed around and it let me do any commands. Then I went to powershell and typed in "lxrun /setdefaultuser root" now I when I start up the bash, it doesnt return anything for my commands. For example: ls, cd. Please help, I want to learn Linux. And yes, I did look at a question that was similar to mine but it didn't help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your going to have to reset WSL since it appears you set the default user to a non-existing user

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1065569/how-to-remove-reset-windows-subsystem-for-linux-on-windows-insider-build-14316/1065579#1065579

Comment: Even though I ran "lxrun /uninstall /full" and then "lxrun /install", it still doesnt show anything up when I type in "cd" or "ls"

Comment: So you ran those commands, removed the WSL feature, then added it back and the behavior remained unchanged?

Comment: Isnt the WSL removed after I run those commands?

Comment: No;  You just reset the instance.  Have you tried my second suggestion?