# Remove / reset permanent rbind mounts on Bash on Ubuntu for Windows (10)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash

Apparently Bash on Ubuntu for Windows (10) cannot be used to run chroot environments for testing purposes.

I tried to setup a Funtoo chroot-installation and it actually worked all fine,
until I noticed my "regular" Ubuntu installation doesn't get rid of the rbind mounts (dev, sys, proc, etc...) that are necessary, even after rebooting Windows.

> paxsali@BIGRIG:~$ mount
>   none on /home/paxsali/CHROOTS/funtoo/proc type
>   proc (rw) /sys on /home/paxsali/CHROOTS/funtoo/sys type none (rw,bind)
>   /dev on /home/paxsali/CHROOTS/funtoo/dev type none (rw,bind) /dev on
>   /home/paxsali/CHROOTS/funtoo/dev type none (rw,bind) /dev on
>   /home/paxsali/CHROOTS/funtoo/dev type none (rw,bind)

That sucks.

I wasn't aware of that and I'd rather use a Virtual Machine instead, now that I know.

Anyhow, is there a known way how to "fix" this back to default **WITHOUT** uninstalling and re-installing the whole thing (which is my Plan B)?

Because it would be a huge plain in the arm re-installing all the packages + local installations (outside of APT) and doing the package upgrades etc...

Here is a description of Plan B:

[How to remove/reset Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows Insider Build 14316](https://superuser.com/questions/1065569/how-to-remove-reset-windows-subsystem-for-linux-on-windows-insider-build-14316/1065579#1065579)

I don't have too high hopes TBH, but I also don't wanna quit just yet.

Any helpful reply will be appreciated.

Comment: So you are asking is there a way to reset your WSL without actually running those commands?  If that isn't what you are asking, then please clarify your question, by modifying it.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I ran mount --rbind commands once that are now permanent, even after rebooting windows. I wanna get rid of the rbind mounts and have the "normal" mtab state that people usually have under Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. Whatever that may be. Is it clearer now?

Comment: rbind has a -n  parameter.  Have you tried that?