# Delete folder from Windows 10 Linux folder

Tags: linux, windows, wsl2

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 for use with WSL2. It's stored in a folder called Linux which shows in explorer as being at the same level as 'Local Disk (C:). [Does that mean desktop?]

Today, as an experiment, I installed ArchLinux on Windows and stored it in the same Linux folder. Later, I decided to delete ArchLinux, but cannot find a way of doing this.

The Linux folder itself has no properties. When I right click on the ArchLinux folder, there is no delete option (ditto for Ubuntu-20.04 folder).

I could get rid of the Ubuntu installation using Control Panel -> Remove Programs, but ArchLinux can't be removed this way.

Does anyone know of a way I can get rid of it?

Comment: Have you tried running `wsl --unregister <DistributionName>`?  You will have to replace `<DistributionName>` with the name of you gave to the ArchLinux WSL2 instance[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1440045/how-do-i-reset-a-manual-installation-of-windows-subsystem-for-linux/1440062#1440062)

Comment: @Ramhound That made it disappear from the Linux folder. Thanks..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Reset A Manual Installation Of Windows Subsystem For Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1440045/how-do-i-reset-a-manual-installation-of-windows-subsystem-for-linux).  Since the command I suggested solved the author's problem, and I have already wrote an answer that explains how to uninstall a WSL2, I have flagged this question as a duplicate.