# Linux Subsystem for Windows: Uninstalling distro removes installed packages?

Tags: linux, windows-10

Suppose I have Ubuntu installed using the Linux Subsystem feature. If I uninstall Ubuntu (using the MS Store), will it also remove all installed Ubuntu packages? Or do I have to do something else to reclaim the disk space?

EDIT: No this is not a question about resetting the bash environment. I want to know whether I can reclaim all the disk space used by Ubuntu + installed packages simply by uninstalling from Windows, or whether there is any other cleanup I have to perform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can the bash shell on Window be completely reset?](https://superuser.com/questions/1282230/how-can-the-bash-shell-on-window-be-completely-reset)