# How do you create a new WSL instance?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I searched over a lot of articles on the internet and cannot find literally any about creating a new WSL instance from command line, wsl.exe. (what is happening.)

I'm not asking `wsl.exe --import`, I'm wanting to create a new flesh Ubuntu instance with specified name.

I have done once or twice in the past this but nowhere to be found the note I took (am I idiot or what). So how can we?

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://superuser.com/questions/1282230/how-can-the-bash-shell-on-window-be-completely-reset/1282268#1282268). How you reset your WSL instance is well documented.  You would first export your current instance, import the clone, then reset which instance you want

Comment: AFAIK, that feature just doesn't exist today, even in the Windows Insider/Preview release.  The best you can do is `wsl --install` a distribution, but it doesn't allow you to assign the name.  See my feature request to the WSL team for that [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6883).  As far as I can tell, even [LxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline) doesn't have that capability.